# Bootstrap dropdown menu (in navigation) no JavaScript

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wonder if it is possible to make the following work:

```css
#keepwidth {
  width: 1000px;
}
.row.top-menu > ul {
  padding: 0;
}
.row.top-menu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.row.top-menu > ul > li > a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #009ec3;
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 123px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 2px #009ec3 solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0;
}
.row.top-menu > ul > li > a:hover {
  background-color: #90d2ec;
  color: #666;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.row.top-menu > ul > li.dropdown:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="keepwidth">
  <div class="row top-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">asdas</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="" role="button">Hover here <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">temp</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">sadsad</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">asdasda</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">sadasdasdsa</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">sadasdsadsa</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">sadasdsasdasdsa</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I do not wish to make use of JavaScript and I do not wish to move the dropdown menu element around (e.g. `margin-top: 0` or `margin: 0`) and I want to make the dropdown appear when hovering both the dropdown menu itself and the button refering to it.

Comment: What is the issue? It seems like if you kill the gap between the "HOVER HERE" and the "temp" boxes the :hover is going to work with no break...

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Bootstrap, you'll need to follow their CSS conventions as explained [here](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) in order to get predictable behavior:

https://jsfiddle.net/Bendrick92/mgny3g87/

```css
#keepwidth {
  width: 1000px;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #009ec3;
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 123px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 2px #009ec3 solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  background-color: #90d2ec;
  color: #666;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="keepwidth">
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
        <a href="#">asdas</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button">
          Hover here <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">temp</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">sadsad</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">asdasda</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">sadasdasdsa</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">sadasdsadsa</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">sadasdsasdasdsa</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```